# Vite running as npm run dev but not directly in terminal

Tags: npm, terminal, vite

I'm facing this bizzare problem with my project. Here are the steps I followed

1. `npm create vite@latest`
2. `cd` to project folder.
3. `npm i`
4. `npm run dev`

This works well but the vite.config.js file is not generated. I tried to run `vite` but then it gives this error.

`vite: The term 'vite' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Also using `npm run dev --host` is not making it available on LAN. Works fine with live-server.

I'm using the latest npm.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem.

- `npm run dev|build|preview` works from shell.
- `vite build --mode other` does not work from shell.
- `npm exec vite -- build --mode other` works from shell.

I wanted a build that would use a .env.other distinct from .env.development or .env.production.

So running:

- `npm exec vite -- build --mode other`
- `npm run preview`

Correctly launches VITE with site-server set to mode 'other' and correctly uses the '.env.other' ENV settings.

I have no idea why on MacOS, I was seeing VITE not properly installed as a bin by npm.  I did all the tricks (delete node_modules, re-install etc.)